# there is a problem adding entity in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, object-initializers

i have a problem in adding entity to database in .net core.all of my code execute with no error but any record inserts in database this is my adding service below

```
        public async Task<int> AddHpl(IFormFile ClinicImgUp, AddHealthPlaceViewModel addHealthPlaceViewModel)
    {
        TableHpl tableHpl = new TableHpl
        {
            TabloTitle = addHealthPlaceViewModel.TabloTitle,
            Address = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Address,
            Services = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Services,
            Others = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Others,
            Personels = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Personels,
            CityCode = addHealthPlaceViewModel.CityCode,
            Recid = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Recid,
            Telegram = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Telegram,
            Email = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Email,
            Website = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Website,
            Instagram = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Instagram,
            PlaceCode = addHealthPlaceViewModel.PlaceCode,
            TableHplphones = new List<TableHplphone>
            {
                new TableHplphone
                {
                    Mobile = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones[0].Mobile,
                    OfficePhone = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones[0].OfficePhone
                },
                new TableHplphone
                {
                    Mobile = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones[1].Mobile,
                    OfficePhone = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones[1].OfficePhone
                }
            }
        };
        if (ClinicImgUp != null && ClinicImgUp.IsImage())
        {

            tableHpl.OfficePic = NameGenerator.GenerateUniqCode() + Path.GetExtension(ClinicImgUp.FileName);
            string imagePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/img", tableHpl.OfficePic);
            await using var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Create);
            ImageResizer.ResizeImage(ClinicImgUp, stream);
        }

        await _context.TableHpls.AddAsync(tableHpl);
        return tableHpl.Hplid;
    }
```

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please see: [What Do You Mean “It Doesn't Work”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147616)

Comment: You aren't saving anything to the database. EF Core doesn't deal with connections and tables, it deals with *objects* , their mapping to tables and persisting *object* changes in batches. You never call `SaveChanges` so nothing is ever saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
 await _context.TableHpls.AddAsync(tableHpl);
```

with this

```
 _context.TableHpls.Add(tableHpl);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

And I think you have to add some validation too:

```
 TableHpl tableHpl = new TableHpl
        {
            TabloTitle = addHealthPlaceViewModel.TabloTitle,
            Address = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Address,
            Services = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Services,
            Others = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Others,
            Personels = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Personels,
            CityCode = addHealthPlaceViewModel.CityCode,
            Recid = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Recid,
            Telegram = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Telegram,
            Email = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Email,
            Website = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Website,
            Instagram = addHealthPlaceViewModel.Instagram,
            PlaceCode = addHealthPlaceViewModel.PlaceCode
        };
if (addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones!=null &&
     addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones.Count > 0
{
 var tableHplphones = new List<TableHplphone>();

   foreach(var phone in addHealthPlaceViewModel.Hplphones)
     {
     
             tableHplphones.Add(  new TableHplphone
                {
                    Mobile = item.Mobile,
                    OfficePhone = item.OfficePhone
                }
           );
      }

tableHpl.TableHplphones=tableHplphones;
}
```

Comment: thank you i dont know why i forgot savechanges()  :)

Comment: due the method use async task, I suggest to use  
await _context.TableHpls.AddAsync(tableHpl);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

Comment: thank you guys it works now.i have another question. suppose that user does not fill in the second textboxes for phone details i mean Hplphones[1] it will be inserted a full null record in database how can i control this issue in object initializer in code above thank you

Comment: @rezasetareh Pls post your TableHpl class too. After this I can only give you some advice

Comment: @Serge thank you i used your code in another way